# PHP cannot see where my function is being redeclared

Tags: php

I am getting this error and cannot find where the function is being redeclared.

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare gera_array() (previously declared in C:\Users\Secret\SkyDrive\Sites e Projetos\Rede Aranha\t4.php:12) in C:\Users\Secret\SkyDrive\Sites e Projetos\Rede Aranha\t4.php on line 10

**Code:**

```
function gera_ecards() {

// Funcao gera array de 5 numeros de 1 a 50 (com duplicados)                
function gera_array() {
    $ecard_rand = array();
    for ($leo = 0; $leo < 5; $leo ++) {
        $ecard_random = mt_rand(1,50);
        array_push($ecard_rand, $ecard_random);
    }
    return $ecard_rand;
}                   
// Funcao remove duplicados da array            
function array_has_dupes($ecard_rand) {
       return count($ecard_rand) !== count(array_unique($ecard_rand));
}

do {
    $ecard_rand = gera_array();
} while (array_has_dupes($ecard_rand));     
sort($ecard_rand);  
$ecard_rand = implode(",", $ecard_rand);    
return $ecard_rand; 
}

for ($leo = 0; $leo < 5; $leo ++) {
 echo gera_ecards(); 
 echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: What is line 10 and 12?

Comment: Are you calling gera_ecards twice?  The second time you call it, it is redeclaring the function gera_array

Comment: Line 10 function gera_array() {

Comment: @daiscog, I see there is bad  logic on it...

Comment: @LeandroCintrao You should not rewrite your question to a new question as the original answers will not make any sense any more. If you have a new question, just post a new question with the actual code and problem.

Comment: @jeroen Didn't realise I'd done that... will be more carefull next time! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php#example-152), your function declaration inside `gera_ecards()` is performed in the global scope and can be seen as a [conditional declaration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php#example-151).

Thus, calling `gera_ecards()` twice will attempt to declare the inner function twice.

If you don't want outside code to call the inner function, you could opt for anonymous functions:

```
$gera_array = function() {
    // ...
};

// Funcao remove duplicados da array            
$array_has_dupes = function($ecard_rand) {
    // ...
};

// etc.
```

Otherwise, just declare those two inner functions outside of `gera_ecards()`.

**Update**

Instead of all that effort to make sure the generated arrays don't have any duplicates, consider using [`shuffle()`](http://php.net/shufle), e.g.:

```
$heap = range(1, 50);
shuffle($heap);
foreach (array_chunk($heap, 5) as $block) {
    sort($block);
    echo join(",", $block), "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You are declaring a function inside a function (why???):

```
function gera_ecards() {

  // Funcao gera array de 5 numeros de 1 a 50 (com duplicados)                
  function gera_array() {

    // ...
```

So every time you call your `gera_ecards()` function, you are declaring function `gera_array()` again.

You should not declare functions in functions.

Comment: `function array_has_dupes($ecard_rand)` is also in there

Comment: function gera_array() gives me the 5 numbers result  21, 12, 34, 43, 50 but may come duplicates

function array_has_dupes() tells me if there are duplicates

function gera_ecards() should give me the result without duplicates : 21, 12, 34, 43, 50

then my loop should give me 5 sequences with no duplicates

for ($leo = 0; $leo < 5; $leo ++) {

echo gera_ecards(); 
echo "<br>";

}

How would I achieve that then?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
function gera_ecards() {

    function gera_array() { }
    function array_has_dupes() { }

}
```

Tries to declare each time you call `gera_ecards()` a new `gera_array()`. There is no such thing like a dedicated private scope for functions declared in functions. They all share the same namespace.

- You could either move the functions outside the enclosing function,

  ```
  function gera_array() { }
  function gera_has_dupes() { }
  function gera_ecards() { }
  ```
- or start programming [object orientated](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) and declare those two functions `private`

  ```
  class Gera {
      private function has_dupes() { }
      private function geraArray() { }
      public function ecards() { }
  }
  ```
- or use Closures (aka [anonymous functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)).

  ```
  function gera_ecards() { 

      $has_dupes = function() { }
      $geraArray = function() { }

      $has_dupes();
      $geraArray();

  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

The explanation for the error is clearly outlined by **jeroen**

To fix this, take the functions out into their own and do it like this:

```
<?php

// Funcao gera array de 5 numeros de 1 a 50 (com duplicados)                
function gera_array()
{
    $ecard_rand = array();
    for ($leo = 0; $leo < 5; $leo++) {
        $ecard_random = mt_rand(1, 50);
        array_push($ecard_rand, $ecard_random);
    }
    return $ecard_rand;
}

// Funcao remove duplicados da array            
function array_has_dupes($ecard_rand) {
    return count($ecard_rand) !== count(array_unique($ecard_rand));
}

function gera_ecards() {
    do {
        $ecard_rand = gera_array();
    } while (array_has_dupes($ecard_rand));
    sort($ecard_rand);
    $ecard_rand = implode(",", $ecard_rand);
    return $ecard_rand;
}

for ($leo = 0; $leo < 5; $leo++) {
    echo gera_ecards();
    echo "<br>";
}

?>
```

Outputs:

```
3,10,12,30,35
9,13,24,26,30
15,27,38,39,42
25,35,44,45,49
12,18,21,40,42
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't nest functions, start programing OOP...
You may have several includes to the same file.

meanwhile:

```
if (!function_exists('gera_array')) {
    function gera_array() { ... }
}
```

Comment: Will take sometime to learn it! function_exists did help thanks!!